# Mapping Multiple Tables into a Single Entity in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity

I'm trying to learn JPA/Hibernate and I'm real green in this field. I tend to usually veer off and try things without knowing much about the API. So I decided to create a simple entity that retrieves information from multiple tables see this is easily implementable with JPA. The reason behind this is, if, hypothetically, the involving tables each has a few hundred columns and we only have a business need to retrieve a very few data, and we only need to focus on retrieval rather than inserts/updates/deletions, I would assume it is best to only retrieve the entire entity (specially if multiple rows need to be returned) then join them across other entities to derive a few columns.

I started up with two simple tables:

```
EMPLOYEES
EMPLOYEE_ID, EMAIL, DEPARTMENT_ID, MANAGER_ID, FIRST_NAME, etc...

DEPARTMENTS
DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME, MANAGER_ID, etc...
```

I want my entity to retrieve only the following columns solely based on `EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID`:

```
EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID
EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID
EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID
DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENT_NAME
```

One thing to notice here is that `EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID` is a self-referencing foreign key to `EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID`.

I might create the following...

```
@SecondaryTable(name="DEPARTMENTS",
    pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="managerId",referencedColumnName="employeeId")
)
@Table(name="EMPLOYEES")
@Entity
public class EmployeesDepartment {

    @Id
    private String employeeId;

    private String managerId;

    private String email;

    private int departmentId;

    @Column(name="DEPARTMENT_NAME",table="DEPARTMENTS")
    private String departmentDesc;

// Setters and getters
}
```

Obviously this doesn't give us the correct answer due to the fact that the join between the secondary table (`DEPARTMENTS`) occurs between its `MANAGER_ID` and `EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID`, rather than `DEPARTMENTS.MANAGER_ID = EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID`.

I cannot replace `referencedColumnName="employeeId"` with `referencedColumnName="managerId"` as managerId of `@Entity EmployeesDepartment` is not a primary key of `EMPLOYEES`.

And I can't do the following:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="managerId",table="DEPARTMENTS",referencedColumnName="employeeId")
private String managerId;
```

My question is, how can I make my join to be on `DEPARTMENTS.MANAGER_ID = EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID` while the `WHERE` clause of the query is based on `EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE.ID`? In other word, how can I have the entity that is mapped to the following query:

```
SELECT
  E.EMPLOYEE_ID,
  E.MANAGER_ID,
  E.DEPARTMENT_ID,
  D.DEPARTMENT_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES E LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D ON E.MANAGER_ID = D.MANAGER_ID
WHERE E.EMPLOYEE_ID = ?
```

Or are there better solution with less side effects, e.g. order of updates of tables, loading, etc.?

Comment: Just do things right: an Employee entity, with a ManyToOne association to the Department entity, and another ManyToOne to the Employee entity for the manager. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-one

Comment: @JBNizet Are you suggesting that there is no way to resolve this issue without creating two separate Entities?

Comment: Yes. The department is shared by several employees. They don't share the same PK. There is a clear ManyToOne association. You could define a view in the database and map that view to a single entity. Or, since you only care about reading very specific data, you could just use JDBC or something much lighter than JPA.